# Emulating Big-Endian Basic Kernel Image

Tags: linux-kernel, qemu, cross-compilation

So after much difficulty, I successfully cross-compiled a basic linux kernel for powerpc to test some big endian code. As I'm on a relatively weak machine and have to compile a relatively large code-base, I did not want an entire distribution, which is why I just compiled the raw kernel.

When I run qemu as `qemu-system-ppc -kernel arch/powerpc/boot/zImage -serial stdio` all I see is the "Welcome to OpenBIOS v1.1" screen. Checking stdout shows:

```
>> =============================================================
>> OpenBIOS 1.1 [Jul 19 2016 06:34]
>> Configuration device id QEMU version 1 machine id 2
>> CPUs: 1
>> Memory: 128M
>> UUID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
>> CPU type PowerPC,750
milliseconds isn't unique.
>> [ppc] Kernel already loaded (0x01000000 + 0x00186dfc) (initrd 0x00000000 + 0x00000000)
>> [ppc] Kernel command line:
```

and nothing else. My suspicion is that I need to somehow create an initial ram disk. However I don't know how to do this in a cross-compiled way?

Note: I also tried adding `-append "root=/dev/ram/ initrd=/bin/bash"` to see if that would work, to no avail.